# Vb.NET rasdial parameters

Tags: vb.net, vpn

I am making a program that schedules the redial of a VPN connection using rasdial however I cannot get my script to pass the correct information to the rasdial.exe program.

For example
  Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "VPN Connection " & ""USERNAME!" & "PASSWORD")

However when this starts it just says "Remote access error 625"

Comment: It means "Invalid information found in the phone book".  Punting: it is probably best to put a space between the username and the password.  Fall in the pit of success with composite formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the best solution is to concatenate the variables before storing them in a database or document because the connection only inputs one parameter.